# IIS 7 SQL Server session management: Where can I find COM object dll for asp classic

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, iis, asp-classic

Basically, I'm following this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx#converttoaspnet_topic5

which states that there's a download link at the top with example code (including COM modules needed for ASP Classic). However, there's no such link/material. Thus, I'm looking to find these COM modules (dlls) somewhere else. But where?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS. I'm running win 2008 server r2, iis 7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple minutes of Googling led me to the [Japanese version of the article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/aa479313.aspx) which does contain a [download link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/0/980e634a-f4ba-43a0-9d6d-119ba7e86403/sessionsample.exe).

Unfortunately that link no longer works (moved, removed etc) but what it did do was expose the originally file name `sessionsample.exe`.

```
http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/0/980e634a-f4ba-43a0-9d6d-119ba7e86403/sessionsample.exe
```

With this information in hand another Google brought up a link on CNet.com to the file.

[Code Sample: Session Sharing Between Classic ASP and ASP.NET](http://download.cnet.com/Code-Sample-Session-Sharing-Between-Classic-ASP-and-ASP-NET/3000-2229_4-10731052.html)

> **WARNING:** Be very careful when using CNet to download software only use the download link at the top of the article (*see image below*) as other links are misleading advertisments that will more then likely lead to spam and/or malware.
>
> [image: download-link]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and effort! I did actually find this one, but it downloads and .exe file so I was a little bit skeptical. Did you try it? I'd prefer to avoid getting a lot of crapware on my comp :)

Comment: I actually tested and it's just an exe that unzips the content.... Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @carl-johan.blomqvist No problem yeah always best to virus scan any executables that claim to be zips for that reason, but I find if you stick to using the "official" cnet download link (as detailed above) you are ok.